# Queue behaving unexpectedly

Tags: python-3.x, queue

(Python 3.6)

Input:

```
from queue import Queue

q = Queue()

for i in range(5):
    q.put(5)

while not q.empty():
    print(q.get())
```

Output:

```
5
5
5
5
5
```

Why not 1, 2, 3, 4, 5? This is a simple FIFO queue.

Comment: Look at the line that says `q.put(5)` and think about what that line is doing.

Comment: That's embarrassing sorry to bother

Comment: No trouble at all. Happens to the best of us.